# Blazor WASM Connecting to Azure SQL Server Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, azure, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM Core Hosted, .NET 7, web application that connects to a database.  My application works fine when running locally but not when I host it on Azure.  When I am working locally, I use the same connection string.  I also am able to connect my MS SQL Server Management Studio to the Azure SQL DB on my development computer just fine. The only issue is when I push my code to Azure that the issue comes up.  Here is my connection string (in appsettings file):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:mycompany.database.myorg.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DBAdmin;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"    
}
```

When my app runs, I will then get this error (only when running on Azure host):

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is
> likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error
> resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer'
> call.  ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A
> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
> a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
> accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)  --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (10060): A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond.

Comment: `mycompany.database.myorg.net` -> this can't be an Azure SQL Database? Do you use a custom domain name somewhere, or does it work locally because your hosts file (or some DNS trickery) makes it work? If this is some kind of redirect or aliasing then you have to make sure the Azure host is also configured to use it... and that if you allow-listed your local IP address that you repeat that process for the IP range of the Azure hosts.

Comment: Hello.  That TCP address comes from the Azure SQL Database Connection String tab, in Azure.  I did change that part to remove any identifying information.  The format is closer to this:  mycompany-sql-server-test.database.myorg.net,1433.  I will check the IP rance

Comment: @AaronBertrand not sure if it matters, but the DB type is "General Purpose - Serverless: Standard"

Comment: If your server name _doesn't_ end in _database.windows.net_ , then as mentioned you have some kind of custom DNS set up. Whoever set that up needs to also set it up for wherever your app is hosted. It might help to expand on "push my code to Azure". Are you publishing to a Azure App Service?

Comment: Also keep in mind that _Serverless_ has a "spin up" time, meaning that if it's asleep it won't respond immediately and could return the error above. But you can wake it up by first connecting from SSMS. But I think your first problem is definitely DNS.

Comment: Yeah, I can connect using SSMS just fine.  I publish by doing a Zip Deploy.  I right click on the Server project and select "Publish" and select to publish to a folder.  I then zip the output up and go to the App Service's Advanced Tools and select Zip Deploy.  I then drap and drop the zip folder